# Custom selection mechanism

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a little slider mechanism which operates as a box/view with a static line image in the center and behind it are pins. The pins look like marks on a ruler. When you slide the marks to the left or right; they keep coming continuously (a loop). And I need to use this as a controller of a view, like a selector. All it needs to do is scroll through a list when the pins are slid. How can I put this together?

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and add a UISwipeGestureRecogniser to it. When the swipe occurs update a ivar and either redraw or animate a bunch of repeating UIimageView subviews.

The latter will be preferable for efficiency and smoothness.